# How do I get this custom exception to work correctly?

Tags: c#, exception

I've created a number game where the player guesses at a random number between 1 and 100. I'm making a custom exception for the number 69 (don't ask XD) to display an exception message if 69 is guessed. This is my first time making a custom exception, and I think I've almost got it right, but I'm uncertain.

```
[Serializable]   
    public class SixtyNineException : Exception
    {
        private int sixtyNine;
        public int NotSixtyNine { get { return sixtyNine; } }
        public SixtyNineException(int sxtnin) : base(String.Format("Do you want to be a joke your whole life? *shakes head*"))
        {
            sixtyNine = sxtnin;
        }
```

I don't know how to get the exception to actually read the number 69. I have everything else set up below and understand how to use a try catch block to test and use the exception. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Currently this exception expects the calling code to provide it with the value `69` (or any numeric value, really).  And then it doesn't do anything with that value.

Since you only plan to *throw* this exception for that specific value, why do you need a number property at all?  Just use your custom message:

```
public class SixtyNineException : Exception
{
    public SixtyNineException() :
      base("Do you want to be a joke your whole life? *shakes head*") { }
}
```

And throw it when you need to:

```
throw new SixtyNineException();
```

---

As an aside, the functionality you're describing here probably shouldn't **be** an exception in the first place.  Exceptions are for errors and handling unexpected things that shouldn't have happened.  Providing a specific output in response to a specific input isn't unexpected or exceptional.  A simple `if` statement in your input handling logic would do the trick.

Comment: You're probably right, and I'm going to change it to an if statement. I just wanted to learn how to create an exception. :^)

Forgive my newness to the concept, but I don't understand how the throw works? I am using a try catch block in my number guessing game. If I wanted to use this exception in a catch block, how do I use it to only flag the number 69?

Thank you so much for your help; I really appreciate it!

Comment: @labmate: A `try` wraps the code that might throw the exception.  So within your `try` is where you'd have an `if` statement which checks the input for the value `69` and throws the exception, then in your `catch` you'd handle the exception by showing a message to the user.  Just describing it sounds overly-complicated because in this case it is.  The same `if` statement that's checking for the value `69` can just show the message to the user, no exceptions needed.

Comment: Thanks, David, I appreciate the explanation. I'll try the overly complicated method so I can see how it works, but will ultimately opt for the simpler if statement. Cheers.